# Application that compiled in .net 3.5 client profile doesn´t run on .net 4 (full)

Tags: wpf

I write wpf application that compiled on .net 3.5 client profile. 
I Install .net 4 (full version not the client profile) run my application, and got an error that says that I must install .net 3.5 client profile.

any Idea

Comment: I think the error is telling you what to do. The .NET 4 Framework does not include .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Then I suggest you install the .NET 3.5 Client Profile.

Comment: isn't it not reasonable to think that if i have .net 4 I didn't need to downgrade?

Comment: Client profiles need special treatments. It is not really downgrading, 3.5 is another version, 4.0 does not replace 3.5.